# printing BST IN order

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print out tree nodes IN order however all that it is coming out are the noes of the lowest depth! I'm not sure what is wrong with my logic so I was wondering if another set of eyes would help me or give me a hint thanks!!

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
6
8
10
```

my code:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.right = None
        self.left = None
        self.value = value


def BST_Insert(root, node):     # root --> root of tree or subtree!
    if root.value is None:
        root = node             # beginning of tree
    else:
        if root.value > node.value:     # go to left
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.left, node)

        if root.value < node.value:    # go to right
            if root.right is None:
                root.right = node
            else:
                BST_Insert(root.right, node)

def inorder_print(root):
    if root.left is not None:
        inorder_print(root.left)
    else:
        print root.value
    if root.right is not None:
        inorder_print(root.right)



r = Node(4)
# left
a = Node(2)
b = Node(1)
c = Node(3)
# right
d = Node(8)
e = Node(6)
f = Node(10)

BST_Insert(r, a)
BST_Insert(r, b)
BST_Insert(r, c)
BST_Insert(r, d)
BST_Insert(r, e)
BST_Insert(r, f)

print "in order:"
inorder_print(r)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the `else` after the the first `if` statement.
Something like the following might work,

```
if left!=null: 
    inorder(left)
print(current_node.val)
if (right!=null):
    inorder(right)
```